# A VLQ flag invalidated by a minor edit

Tags: discussion, support, flagging, low-quality-posts

I have flagged [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1170463/250300) as *very low quality* since it barely can help OP to solve their problem (see [my comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266180/tried-to-make-usb-stick-from-os-x/1170463#comment1953397_1170463) there).

The answer got two “Recommend Deletion” votes when [reviewed](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/975057) but then the review was invalidated as shown in the [post’s timeline](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1170463/timeline).

[image]

The reason to invalidate the review was an [edit made to the answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1170463/revisions) which unfortunately did not fix the nature of the answer, just like the following edit.

So my flag is marked “helpful” now…

[image]

…but the low-quality answer (assuming the community consensus from the upvotes to [my comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266180/tried-to-make-usb-stick-from-os-x/1170463#comment1953397_1170463) and no disagreeing reply) is remaining there and I cannot flag it again.

[image: screenshot of the flagging window with VLQ grayed out]

I could use the “not an answer” flag but I find this inappropriate since the post *tries* to answer the question.

What should I do now?

Comment: I'm not sure about the next step but there's no need to worry. People barely look at the posts with negative score since it indicates that it's a bad advice or won't help anyway. Also, there are many posts with <=-3 score still existing on the site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer was indeed not helpful since the `~` are absolutely fine, as you pointed out. I have now deleted it.

Next time, if a post requires attention and none of the standard flags fit (or are available to you), just raise a custom mod flag letting us know what the issue is. That way the mods can take care of it.

Thanks!